# How to setup splunk summary index?

Tags: splunk

I'm a bit confused with setting up summary index in `splunk`.
I have an index name `index_1` which receive logs from my app.
There are much too many logs, and I need to save an aggregation of them.

I have tried setting up the summary index from [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.1/Knowledge/Usesummaryindexing) to an index name `summary`,
but when I search the index there are no log entries.

My search is as follow:

```
index=index_1 ... level>30
```

I couldn't understand when to use the `collect` command and when setting up from the web ui is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your search, `index=index_1 ... level>30` should reduce the number of events being returned, and to only those events you want to store in the summary index. In this case, it looks like you're only interested in keeping events where `level>30`.

At the end of your search, you need to include the collect command. The collect command will take the remaining events, and write it to the named index, so `collect index=summary`

Overall, your search should look like

```
index=index_1 ... level>30 | collect index=summary
```

Here is an older blog post discussing summary indexing that may help you understand the process and good practices around using it.
https://davidveuve.com/tech/how-i-use-summary-indexes-in-splunk/

Comment: Running the `collect` with the correct summary index, I see that the job write "successfully wrote file to '/opt/splunk/...'" but when I run a search on the summary index, no result found..

Comment: are you searching for all time. is it an all in one server, or separate search head or search head cluster